# Profiling ncurses application with instruments on OSX

Tags: xcode, instruments, ncurses

I have a C command-line application that uses ncurses and I am using Xcode 4.4 (OSX Lion) to develop this. So far I have been running the code from the terminal after building it with Xcode. Now I need to profile the multi-threaded part of the code and I want to use Instruments for this. If I do run 'profile' in Xcode, it fires up Instruments, but crashes immediately possibly for the same reason that it crashes in Xcode, namely that it can't open the terminal. If I switch off all curses parts of the code, it runs fine in Instruments, but obviously I get no output (and it is crucial for me to follow the code progress). And finally, if I run the code from the terminal and try to attach to the process from within Instruments, I get the following message "Attaching requires that the target utilizes CoreFoundation.framework" when doing memory profiling and "Current Instrumentation Disallow Attach" when doing multicore profiling.

Can anyone please explain to me how this can be done, that is to profile the code and simultaneously see the curses output in a terminal window?